# Changing stack order between different rows flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Goodmorning. I am trying to change the stacking order in a flexbox situation, where there are 2 columns, but the first column contains a spot where the second column needs to be put in between. So when on mobile I need them to be ordered different than source order.

This is on large

```
col 1     col 2
----------==============
[A]         [C]
[B]
```

Where A and B are in one column, and C is in the other

But on small breakpoint, it needs to be

```
[A]
[C]
[B]
```

Is this possible using just Flexbox?

So to clarify. The HTML structure is as such:

```
row
  column
    divA
    divB

  column
    divC
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/Kotrotsos/pen/MmVjJw)

```css
.a { background-color: green; }
.b { background-color: red; }
.c { background-color: blue; }

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.column {
  flex: 1;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row {
     flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  
  <div class="column">
      <div class="a">A</div>
      <div class="b">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column c">C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this a full page layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

With original html and `display: contents` allows c to take full height without adding heights when in desktop.  Also better solves original problem of how to change order of elements in two separate divs

```css
.a {
  background-color: green;
  order: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.b {
  background-color: red;
  order: 3;
  width: 100%;
}

.c {
  background-color: blue;
  order: 2;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;     /* add this so you don't need the extra wrapper div */
}

.column {
  width: 50%; /* start off width children being 50% width */
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .column {
     width: 100%;
  }
  .column:first-child {
     display: contents;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
      <div class="a">A</div>
      <div class="b">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column c">C</div>
</div>
```

**Original Answer**

You can achieve what you want with media queries and order:

```css
.a {
  background-color: green;
  order: 1;
}

.b {
  background-color: red;
  order: 3;
}

.c {
  background-color: blue;
  order: 2;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;     /* add this so you don't need the extra wrapper div */
}

.row>div {
  width: 50%; /* start off width children being 50% width */
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .row>div {
     /* for small screens */
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is making A and B in one column and c in other column ? thats was great answer btw :)... but the c is not stretching to have same height as A and B!!

Comment: @Chiller it's a mixture of the flex wrap, row direction and width causing the column effect - I wasn't sure if they needed the c column to take full height - I can change the answer so it does

Comment: I think i understand now ! ... the challenge will be on the height of c.

Comment: @Chiller unfortunately it would mean setting a height on the row: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rmdWVz

Comment: Awesome solution @Chiller Thanks! I can work with this

Comment: @Marco its Pete 's solution.. You should thank him :)

Comment: If you're going to alter the HTML, why not also switch the source order of b and c? Then you don't need to use the *order* property. Still, good answer IMO.