# how to pass one on a second column at the end of 5 elements?

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

I would like to be able to pass the 5th element in another column as on the picture I'm attaching.

[here my picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuN5J.png)

I've tried a few things with flexbox

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="field">element 1</div>
    <div class="field">element 2</div>
    <div class="field">element 3</div>
    <div class="field">element 4</div>
    <div class="field">element 5</div>
    <div class="field">element 6</div>
</div>
```

My sass file:

```
 container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    .field {
      &:nth-child(5){
        display: flex;
      }
    }
```

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can user order for each column

```
.item:nth-child(3n+1) { order: 1; }
.item:nth-child(3n+2) { order: 2; }
.item:nth-child(3n)   { order: 3; }
```

Comment: Yes, but how do you get it to line up again on a new column?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911787/changing-stack-order-between-different-rows-flexbox

Comment: Yes thank you, but I don't want to create two columns. Just say that the sixth element is at the top right. So it's not possible?

Answer (score 1):

CSS-Grid can do that provided you determine the maximum number of rows.

Example with 5 rows...

```css
.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, max-content);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.field {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: .5em;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="field">element 1</div>
  <div class="field">element 2</div>
  <div class="field">element 3</div>
  <div class="field">element 4</div>
  <div class="field">element 5</div>
  <div class="field">element 6</div>
</div>
```

Example with 15 items and 4 rows...

```css
.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, max-content);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.field {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: .5em;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="field">element 1</div>
  <div class="field">element 2</div>
  <div class="field">element 3</div>
  <div class="field">element 4</div>
  <div class="field">element 5</div>
  <div class="field">element 6</div>
  <div class="field">element 7</div>
  <div class="field">element 8</div>
  <div class="field">element 9</div>
  <div class="field">element 10</div>
  <div class="field">element 11</div>
  <div class="field">element 12</div>
  <div class="field">element 13</div>
  <div class="field">element 14</div>
  <div class="field">element 15</div>
</div>
```